# What is non-standard input/output/error

Tags: stdout, stdin, stderr

I have read books/tutorials which mention **standard input/output/error**. My understanding is that:

1. **standard input/output/error** are concepts of a process (i.e. if someone mentions **standard input/output/error**, they are actually talking about **standard input/output/error** of a particular process. It doesn't make sense to talk about **standard input/output/error** of a file.)
2. Standard input in Linux for most processes is keyboard and standard output/error is screen.

My question: if there's the *standard*, what is the *non-standard* input/output/error of a process in Linux?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file descriptors 0, 1, and 2 are provided by default when a process is `exec`ed, and associated with `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`. If a process needs additional I/O channels, it opens non-standard file descriptors starting from 3.

For 1.: Yes

For 2.: That's true for interactive processes whose I/O is not redirected. Other processes (e.g. `cron` jobs) can well have different associations.

Comment: For 2, I'd say that is a result of "most processes" being started from a shell whose own standard file descriptors are a terminal. *All* processes inherit the standard file descriptors from their parent. (Even redirections are instructions to the shell to substitute other descriptors in place of the shell's own. A process is unaware of *how* its own standard descriptors are set.)

Comment: Indeed, for 2 it's only the case that they are normally whatever the process inherits from its parent, which, for a command typed in an interactive session, will be the interactive device. Plenty of processes are started in contexts nothing like that.